# Bokeh - access the axis label from within CustomJS trigger an error but works in Python code

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a standard figure

```
p=figure(plot_width = 1200, plot_height = 600, x_axis_label= "cities", y_axis_label="population")
```

I can change the label of either axis with

```
p.yaxis.axis_label = "something else"
```

Although if I create a `CustomJS` to change the label, this won't work.
When I pass to the `CustomJS` the `yaxis.axis_label` I get an error:

`AttributeError: '_list_attr_splat' object has no attribute 'axis_label'`

This is the JS code:

```
callback=CustomJS(args=dict(label=p.yaxis.axis_label), code="""

    var y_label = label;
    y_label.set("something else");

""")
```

If instead I pass just `p.yaxis` and then try to access in JS code the `axis_label`, I get the following error on the web page:

`typeError: y_label is undefined`

This is the JS code:

```
callback=CustomJS(args=dict(label=p.yaxis), code="""

    var y_label = label.axis_label;
    y_label.set("something else");

""")
```

While you can clearly see that it was instantiated in the beginning.

Is this a bug in Bokeh or there is something that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plots may have more than one y axis, so `p.yaxis` is actually a list containing all the y axes on a plot:

```
>>> p.yaxis
[<bokeh.models.axes.LinearAxis at 0x106fa2390>]
```

However, more often than not, there is only y-axis. So Bokeh has a convenience that allows for setting `p.yaxis.label = "foo"` without a subscript. [This is described in the documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#axes) But this only works from Python, it is not technically possible on the Javascript side. There, you will will have to be explicit, and treat `p.yaxis` as the list that is, e.g.

```
p.yaxis[0].axis_label = "foo"
```

Alternatively, you could pass `p.yaxis[0]` in the `args` dict from the Python side, which would allow you to refer to refer to it directly:

```
callback=CustomJS(args=dict(axis=p.yaxis[0]), code="""
    axis.axis_label = "foo"
""")
```

Comment: I see; indeed I can  access the property if I pass the [0]. Although the assignment does not seem to reflect in the graph (also there is a typo on the name of the axis_label property name). Do I have to trigger the change manually in the JS code?